# Pc blocking doorway during combat

Tags: dnd-5e

Playing a DnD and our barbarian rushed into a room and stopped just through the doorway. Was surrounded by enemies. Dm said no allies behind barbarian would be able to get a attack because barbarian was blocking any attacks. The door size was just under a 5ft sq. Is this accurate? The map was tresendar manor area 10 north door .here is a picture of what I mean the orange is enemy blue is friendly [image]

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Does the linked Q&A address your issue? If not, please edit/comment to clarify how your question is distinct.